# Javascript - Function Parameter As Variable

Tags: javascript

I've searched a bit for this answer, so here is what I'm trying to do - if possible

```
function foo(variable){
```

If I call the function, how would I go about passing that parameter as a variable?

```
function foo(9){
    var stuff = 9;

//then pass variable to rest of script
```

Here is the whole code:

```
function ajaxgetter(variable) {
    var stuff = variable;
    var mygetrequest = new ajaxRequest();
    mygetrequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (mygetrequest.readyState == 4){
            if (mygetrequest.status == 200 || window.location.href.indexOf("http") == -1){
                document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = mygetrequest.responseText;
            } else {
                alert("An error has occured making the request");
            }
        }
    }

    var namevalue = encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("name9"+stuff).value);
    var agevalue = encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("age9"+stuff).value);
    var utvalue = encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("ut9"+stuff).value);
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "<center><b>Loading...</b></center><br><center><img src='images/ajax-loader1.gif' /></center>";
    mygetrequest.open("GET", "newdealerfinder.php?location="+namevalue+"&distance="+agevalue+"&ut="+utvalue1"&r="+ Math.random(), true)mygetrequest.send(null);
}
```

Onclick event (PHP):

```
$javacounter = 1;
if($miles1 > 2) {
                echo "<form action='' method='get' />
                <input type='hidden' value='$city->lat,$city->lng' id='name9$javacounter' name='name9$javacounter' />
                <input type='hidden' value='$currentunixtime' id='ut9$javacounter' name='ut9$javacounter' />
                <input type='hidden' value='$distance' id='age9$javacounter' name='age9$javacounter' />
                <input type='button' value='Coming Soon' onClick='ajaxgetter($javacounter)' />
                </form>";
                $javacounter++;
            }
```

Location of script:
[Here](http://trucktiresearch.com)

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do. Do you have a complete code example?

Comment: By writing `function foo (bar) {...`, you are already declaring the function arguments, so when you call foo(9), `bar` will have value 9 and it exists as a local variable in that function scope (accessible within the scope and inner functions) .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is your function definition

```
function foo(variable){
    var stuff = variable;
    alert(stuff);
    return stuff;
}
```

Then you call it and pass a value like so

```
var x = foo(9); //will alert 9
// use x..

// then pass variable to rest of script
```

Not sure what the "rest of script" is. But if you're looking for this to be accessed outside the function, you need to do some research on Javascript variable scope and using globals (as opposed to passing arguments).

Tho you can return a variable from your function in order to use it throughout the script as well. I updated the code the show that...

Comment: I added something similar to that in my edited code above, and it doesn't seem to work.  For whatever reason, onclick isn't firing.

Comment: @Go3Team I don't see you setting an `onclick` event

Comment: @Go3Team not sure. syntax seems fine. are you positive its not firing? tried setting `alert("hello");` at the top of `ajaxgetter()`?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying to get the result from the function call and use it in the rest of the script?

```
var foo = function (variable) {
    // do some stuff with variable
    return variable;
}

var result = foo(9);
// do whatever with result in rest of script
```